# Angular 4.3 - How to delete parameters in HttpParams

Tags: angular, api

I have a HttpParams like this:

```
private filter: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
[...]
this.filter = this.filter.append('page','1');
this.filter = this.filter.append('pageSize','50');
this.filter = this.filter.append('name','xxx');
[...]
```

Now I want to delete some params to get my api call like this:
http://xxxxxxxxx/call/?pagesize=50&name=xxx

I tried this:

```
[...]
this.filter = this.filter.delete('page');
[...]
```

But what I have is this:
http://xxxxxxxxx/call/?page=&pagesize=50&name=xxx

The delete method only delete the value of the parameter, not the whole parameter.

How can I delete the whole parameter?

Before this code I used URLSearchParams delete method and it worked properly.

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Comment: That works fine, Pranay.

Thanks!

Comment: welcome ..happy to help

Comment: I'm very sorry but that solution don't work for me. I tried again and I can' delete the whole parameter. (Maybe cache or some fake data make me think about it solved that... :S)

Answer (score 2):

Had same Problem, this is worked for me `this.filter.params['map'].delete('page');`

Answer (score 1):

can you try out as below

```
 delete this.filter['page']
```

Comment: I'm very sorry but that solution don't work for me. I tried again and I can' delete the whole parameter. (Maybe cache or some fake data make me think about it solved that... :S )